# Add 3d column values in hoverinfo when using ggplot2 object in ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

my data frame:

```
structure(list(CNT = c("Albania", "Algeria", "Argentina (Ciudad Autónoma de Buenos)", 
"Australia", "Austria", "B-S-J-G (China)", "Belgium", "Brazil", 
"Bulgaria", "Canada"), Female = c(417.75, 363.07, 446.03, 490.99, 
483.13, 528.19, 499.74, 369.55, 442.16, 511.14), Male = c(408.55, 
356.5, 467.31, 496.76, 510.1, 534.01, 514, 385.04, 440.32, 520.17
)), .Names = c("CNT", "Female", "Male"), row.names = c(NA, 10L
), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to plot the data using a ggplot2 object and not plot_ly so that on hovering the values of all three variables are shown.

If I do the way I want only Male and Female appears on hovering:

```
p<-ggplot(df, aes(Female, Male)) +
  geom_point() 
ggplotly(p)
```

I want the country name to appear as well. Looking on the web I figure it out how to do in plot_ly:

```
plot_ly( df, x=df$Female , y=df$Male, text=df$CNT,
hoverinfo="text+x+y")
```

I want to achieve the same result but using a ggplot2 object as in the example above when using object p.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Female, y = Male, text = paste("CNT:", CNT))) + geom_point()
ggplotly()
```